# How do I script a password change for a SQL server login?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Just what the title says, I need to change the password for an existing sql server login and I want to do it via sql script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ALTER LOGIN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx

Answer (score 45):

If the user already has the ALTER ANY LOGIN permission (i.e. the user can change any password for any user) then this works:

```
alter login mylogin with password = 'mylogin'
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to make every user in your system a superuser, add a parameter of the old password for the same command:

```
alter login mylogin with password = 'mylogin' old_password='oldpassword'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
alter login mylogin with password = 'mylogin'
```