# How to change the password of 'sa' using sql queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to change the password of 'sa' using sql queries in sql server? can we read datas with sql statements and execute commands if we dont have xp_cmdshell procedure enabled or dont have permission? any other ways to achieve these?

Comment: This question does not make much sense.

Comment: Did you see [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I script a password change for a SQL server login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923/how-do-i-script-a-password-change-for-a-sql-server-login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
GO
ALTER LOGIN [LOGIN_NAME] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [LOGIN_NAME] WITH PASSWORD=N’NewPassword’ MUST_CHANGE
GO
```